# How to best leverage ASP.Net Core Identity for a unique form of multitenancy in a Blazor Server app

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I am in the process of designing a Blazor Server app that sits on top of a single MSSQL db.

I have done a fair amount of research and learning on the subject but I am still very new to Core Identity, so I need to better understand how it is meant to be used so that I can properly design the Authentication and Authorization pieces.

The app will consist of organizations. Users can belong to one or more organizations and within each organization, can belong to one of two roles: Coach or Student. But the Coach in one organization could be a student in another organization, and a student could be a student of more than one organization. But all of this should be tied to a single user account/login. If a user belongs to more than one organization, they will be presented with a screen to select which organization they want to access after completing the login process. Once they have selected the organization, their activity and access will be limited to that organization.

What would be the proper way to handle this type of arrangement? Since one user could be a coach in one org and a student in another, are roles the proper way to handle that? Or would those be claims where for example I would store the ID of the organization as the value of a claim called "Coach" or "Student"? Or some other way?

Initially, I was planning to only use Identity for Authentication and then use my own custom logic to perform Authorization based on these criteria, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

Thanks in advance for your guidance and recommendations on this.

Comment: Have just provided my thoughts on a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960908/i-want-to-multiple-jwt-bearer-authentication-but-it-might-be-not-necessary/71961356#71961356

Comment: Thanks, Neil. I can see that there are similarities between that post and mine, as well as the scenario you outlined in your solution, but I'm not sure I understand the vernacular. Does your answer on that post suggest that Roles and Claims have nothing to do with it, and instead it is based on Tokens?

Comment: A Jwt Security Token includes the claims.  So the answer is both.  The solution can use Tokens to hold the Claims (including Roles), which are encrypted and sent to the client.  When the client sends a request to the server, it includes the token in the header, which the server can decrypt and get at all those claims stored in there.

Comment: sound like similar to azure ad.. If you have Azure ad, you may try to [integrate azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-blazor-server) into your blazor server app

Comment: Thanks Tiny, but I'm not using active directory or Azure for this project. Not trying to integrate with any other SSO providers or anything, just managing application users, roles (and claims?).

Comment: Thanks, Neil. To clarify I am using Cookies, not JWTBearer. Not planning to configure external providers or SSO, just trying to use Core Identity to manage application users and what they can access. I'm still not clear on how I would create the authorizations I asked about in the OP though. Would "Coach (for a given org)" and "Student (for a given org)" be represented by roles or claims?