# I want to multiple JWT Bearer Authentication but It might be not necessary

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an application to solve the management problem of businesses. I am using jwt tokens to access services in this application.

A business can have multiple business accounts. That is, business owners can switch and control between their businesses account from the admin panel. Business accounts can be registered with staff and access services as permitted by the business owner. Staff members can register for multiple business accounts and access services for each business account to the extent permitted by the business owner.

I think two tokens will be needed for this system. After user login, one master token to access user services and another second token to access business services.

The question in my mind is I can place the business claims in a single token without the need for two tokens, but after the user login, the token is generated, so the business may not be able to select. If the business cannot choose, it cannot access the service rights because there are no claims in the token.

What if I generate a token for 5 minutes and use that token for the access to get my business service and then generate my other token after the business account is selected?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand

> but after the user login, the token is generated, so the business may
> not be able to select. If the business cannot choose, it cannot access
> the service rights because there are no claims in the token.

But, the following may help:

I had a similar challenge whereby one user:

- can access multiple groups
- can only be working in the context of one group at a time
- can switch between group context at any time
- may have different permissions depending on which group context they are operating in

My solution has been:

- When user signs in they receive the initial token.
- When they select a group context to work in a call is made to an API to 'SwitchGroup'.
- This API checks user can access the group at all, and then builds a token with the permissions for that group.  The token is returned from the 'SwitchGroup' API.
- It is then the responsibility of the client to use that new token when making future API calls in the context of the group they just switched to.

Alternatively, you could build one token at login time that includes all of their claims across all groups that they might access.

Alternatively, you could return a list of tokens, one for each business context, in the original login and the client caches these and uses the appropriate token depending on which group context they wish to operate in.

Comment: After the user has successfully logged in, a token is generated to access the api service, that is, the user receives the token information returned from the login service. But it needs a different token to access the business service. After logging in, the user sends a request about which businesses he is registered with, then the api returns the list of businesses he is registered with, the user chooses which business account to log in to, and a new token is generated. to summarize, can there be a separate token for user services and a separate token for business services? is it necessary?

Comment: Assuming that the user is malicious, what happens if user constantly sends a SwitchGroup call to your api service?

Comment: If the business service is issuing its own tokens (separately from the initial user login), instead of using a single sign-on, then, yes, you would need a second token to access the business services.  If they both use the same token issuer, then you could work with one token.

Comment: If they keep making SwitchGroup calls then they'll keep getting new tokens, which is not a problem in itself.

Comment: I'm placing claims inside tokens so that it can access business services. For example, you can think of "Business.GetMyBusiness" or "Business.GetMyStuffs" as roles. When the user sends a request to the business service and my identity server decrypts the token, I give you the information that you are authorized for this service or not according to the roles in the token. The reason I split the tokens in two is because I will be converting my app to a super app, the first token holds the roles to access user services after login, the second token is generated using the first token.